# Closed-form expression for sum of Vandermonde matrix elements

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, matrices, polynomials, discrete-mathematics

Given the Vandermonde matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1^0 & 1^1 & 1^2 & ... & 1^n \\
2^0 & 2^1 & 2^2 & ... & 2^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
N^0 & N^1 & N^2 & ... & N^n\end{pmatrix}$$

the row sums can be calculated using the closed-form expression for a geometric series (or the column sums calculated using the Bernoulli expression for n-th powers).  Is there a closed-form expression to simplify the sum of all elements within the Vandermonde matrix?  That is, is there a closed-form expression for:

$$\begin{align*}
1+n+\sum_{r=2}^{N}\frac{(1-r^{n+1})}{(1-r)}
\end{align*}$$
Or alternatively, is there any way to expedite summing all elements within the Vandermonde matrix?  Thanks.

Comment: Your expression doesn't make sense for $r=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the expression to begin with r = 2.

Comment: Do you need an exact solution or asymptotic? The latter is easy to obtain by approximating sums with integrals

Comment: An exact solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you notice $n = N-1$?

Comment: That is true if it is square, but the matrix may not be square.